# Casting issue causing exception when data is within the range

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core-1.1

I have a .NET Core web-service that expose api. It has a database table like below.

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    [Name] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Points FLOAT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Employee] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([Id] ASC )
)
```

This table was scaffolded to code as follows.

```
public partial class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Points { get; set; }
    }
```

This class is consumed as below.

```
var employees = context.Employee.ToList();
```

This code is running fine with few happy customers. So far so good.

When work for the Version 2 of same application started,  I realised that data getting stored in the Points column doesn't  need any precision, it can actually fit in a tinyint range. As a result, I changed the data type to tinyint for version 2 but we still have customer using version 1 of application . The class in version 2 now looks as follows with Points column has a type of byte.

```
public partial class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public byte Points { get; set; }
    }
```

With this change, my thinking was that since the data contained in table actually is all within the range of tinyint, there should not be any issues for Version 1 code base. However now the application version 1 code encounters exception when executing following line.

```
var employees = context.Employee.ToList();
```

Below is the exception.

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SqlServerQueryCompilationContextFactory
>   - An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query. System.InvalidOperationException: An exception occured while
>   reading a database value for property 'Employee.Points '. The expected
>   type was 'System.Double' but the actual value was of type
>   'System.Byte'. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object
>   of type 'System.Byte' to type 'System.Double'.    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.EntityMaterializerSource.TryReadValue[TValue](ValueBuffer
>   valueBuffer, Int32 index, IPropertyBase property)    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.EntityMaterializerSource.ThrowReadValueException[TValue](Exception
>   exception, Object value, IPropertyBase property)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.EntityMaterializerSource.TryReadValue[TValue](ValueBuffer
>   valueBuffer, Int32 index, IPropertyBase property)    at
>   lambda_method(Closure , ValueBuffer )    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.UnbufferedEntityShaper`1.Shape(QueryContext
>   queryContext, ValueBuffer valueBuffer)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.AsyncQueryMethodProvider.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<_ShapedQuery>b__0(ValueBuffer
>   vb)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.SelectAsyncEnumerable`2.SelectAsyncEnumerator.<MoveNext>d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.SelectAsyncEnumerable`2.SelectAsyncEnumerator.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)

I understand that casting from double to byte causes a data loss but in this case all the values int his table are between 1 to 5.  Where is my thinking wrong here?

Comment: If the values are all within range then why don't you alter your database to match the expected type, truncating the values?

Comment: @RossBush Getting this error after altering the  table.